# custom error pages not to be accesible directly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2, errordocument

In my .htaccess I do the following

The then php script takes the user to the relevant page / displays the relevant text

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?e=500
ErrorDocument 503 /error.php?e=503
```

For some of the errors I am attempting to send an automatic email.

1)How can I prevent the page from being accessed directly if not from apache e.g just by someone typing `error.php?e=503`

2)How can I get the last url visited (the url that triggered the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?e=500
ErrorDocument 503 /error.php?e=503

# block direct access to /error.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+error\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

**(2)** Inside `/error.php` access original URI using:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```